# How to post each row with file to controller using ajax

Tags: c#, ajax

I am creating dynamic textbox and file browse in table and
Posting complete table rows and each row that contains the file.
please help me to find out the solution.
**Thanks In advance**
My code is below

**Html**

```
<div class="row">
    <form id="multiformROw">
        <table id="tblMulRow">
            <thead>
                <tr>Invoice</tr>
                <tr>File</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
             
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="uploadData()" />
    </form>
    <input type="button" value="Row" onclick="AddRows()" />
</div>
```

**Script**

**createing table body dynamically**

```
function AddRows() {
        var s = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            s = "<tr>";
            s += "<td>" + "<input type='text' name='Id'/>" + "<td>";
            s += "</tr>";
            s += "<tr>";
            s += "<td>" +"<input type='file' name='invFile'/>" + "<td>";
            s += "</tr>";

            $("#tblMulRow tbody").append(s);
        }
        
    }
```

**Post Data To controller**

```
 function uploadData() {
            var formData = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                var invData = {};
                invData.Id = i;
                invData.invFile = $('#multiformROw input[type=file]').get(i).files[0].name;
                formData.push(invData);
            }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Diagnosis/postInvoice",
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function () {

            }
        })
    }
```

**model Class**

```
 public class MultipleFileUpload
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public HttpPostedFileBase invFile { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult postInvoice(List<MultipleFileUpload> formData)
        {
           //Logic
        }
```

Comment: invData.invFile push file instead of file name.

Comment: Thanks for your response but still same.